# Verifying the answer of T(n) = T(n/2) + n(2 - cos n) using Master Theorem

Tags: algorithms

$T(n) = T(n/2) + n(2 - \cos n)$

I want to verify my answer for this recurrence.
Using the [extended master theorem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/advanced-master-theorem-for-divide-and-conquer-recurrences/), $\log_ba = \log_2 1 = 0$

Comparing $f(n)$ with $\Theta(n^k \log ^p n)$ we get $k= 1$

Now $\log_ba < k$ and $p = 0$ which is case 3a of the master theorem

So $T(n) = \Theta(n)$

Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=2^p$ and $U(p)=T(n)$ then we have the telescopic $U(p)-U(p-1)+2^p(2-\cos(2^p))$

$$U(p)=U(0)+\sum\limits_{k=1}^p 2^k(\overbrace{2-\cos(2^k)}^{\in\ [1,2]})$$

Since we are only interest in a $\Theta$ order we can just lay some $c\in[1,2]$ and get  $U(p)=U(0)+c(2^{p+1}-2)=\Theta(2^p)$ giving $T(n)=\Theta(n)$.